# Flask return json sequence

Tags: json, flask, sequence

Flask need return a json, just like as follow:

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():  
    user = [{'name':'tom','age':2},{'name':'jerry','age':3}];
    return jsonify(user)
```

but the response is:

```
[
  {
    "age": 2, 
    "name": "tom"
  }, 
  {
    "age": 3, 
    "name": "jerry"
  }
]
```

I need a right sequence. Heeeeeeelp!

Comment: I think you're looking for JSON_SORT_KEYS, as described here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#JSON_SORT_KEYS

Comment: Ur right，Solved！But only works with Python3.x！

Answer (score 0):

This is technically a duplicate question, but I thought I'd answered it anyways!

So the problem is that Flask doesn't "pretty print" JSON text by default, so you have to change your config. You can do that by adding this one line!

```
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = True
```

-Kirshan